# Can I add a div tag to my google Blogger page title?

Tags: html, css, title, blogspot

-Edited because my original question was too broad-

I'd like to add a div tag object to my google Blogger page titles.

The div tag is:

```
<div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='follow_buttons' data-app-id='XXXXXXXX' expr:data-title='data:post.title' expr:data-url='data:post.url'></div>
```

I'm hoping the result will be the title of the page in line with my social media bar (the div tag).

Ex.

Title: My Links (Facebook icon) (Twitter icon) (Pinterest Icon) (etc.)

Body: Stuff in the body of the page following in-line title and social icons.

When I edit "My links" page in the blogger editor there are 2 options:

1. Compose- this option allows for adding text and images.
2. HTML- This is where I can add formatting codes.

In the HTML tab the only code I have in "My Links" page so far is:

```
<style> .post h3 {font-size:40px !important;}  </style>
```

This code makes my page title 40px.

I tried the following code to try to achieve the result that I'm currently looking for now:

```
<style> .post h3 {font-size:40px !important;} <div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='follow_buttons' data-app-id='XXXXXXXX' expr:data-title='data:post.title' expr:data-url='data:post.url'></div> </style>
```

This just resulted in error.

I really don't have a clue on what else to try.

Thanks in advance and I'd be glad to answer any questions, make clarifications, or to make any revisions to my post. Happy day.

Comment: post your code . What have your tried so far ?

Comment: Before posting any que here on Stackoverflow try considering [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is there anything I can do to promote conversation on this topic?